# trying to update/ insert 20k records in mysql but its working very slow any suggestions?

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-ec2, innodb

trying to update/ insert 20k records in mysql but its working very slow any suggestions ?
My Server configuration is 
DB engine : innodb.
server : Amazon Ec2
Ram : 7GB

I have used for loop on 20k records and as per my conditions am inserting and updating the records.
to insert/update records it takes around 45 to 60 minutes.

Comment: You must go for Bulk inserts or Bulk updates which will happen faster

Comment: Can you try my answer

Answer (score 0):

You must use Bulk insert

```
  INSERT INTO table_name ( field1, field2,...fieldN )
                   VALUES
                   ( a1, a2,...aN ),( b1, b2,...bN ),..;
```

concatenate the row values and call it as single query

Comment: Thanks,
I have to insert calculated amount and after insert needs to update tax related fields as per settings so that's why i am not using bulk insert

Comment: Post your code here then. How do we know that  what are you trying to do after insert

Answer (score 0):

If you iterate and update each record separately that is normal.

There is a faster way:

Iterate through data to insert and set up max package to be updated (1k) with one sql statement:

`INSERT INTO table (field,...) VALUES (va1,...), (vb1,...) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE field=VALUE(field),ID=LAST_INSERT_ID(ID);` where `ID is your primary key`;

This way with few inserts you can update or create new rows and keep your primary index in check (not bloating with every duplicate insert).

That should speed up things to less than a minute.

Comment: there are 3 update queries after insert for same record

Comment: If you setup proper `UNIQUE()` indexes on that table, you can only use that `INSERT` statement and do it by bulk. SQL will do the rest.